# on postfix reject mail if envelope recipient != header To

Tags: postfix

So,

for certain envelope recipients, I'd like to check if there is a matching TO header, and reject the email if it doesn't exist.

I think I'm getting into filter territory here - or perhaps a conditional header_check ?

so basically:

```
if envelope recipient == X then
  if TO: != X or CC: != X or BCC: != X then
     reject email
  fi
fi
```

Pointers from postfix gurus appreciated.

Comment: Do you use dovecot on the server along with the postfix? Would it be acceptable for you to implement it as dovecot sieve filter?

Comment: nope - the machine just just sends on mail to the appropriate machine via smtp. I'm actually hoping to reject the mail before the transaction with sending server concludes.